# Why mongoose populate works but virtual populate doesn't?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have the following schema as per the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals):

```
const toolRecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
});

toolRecordSchema.virtual("user", {
  ref: "User",
  localField: "userId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  justOne: true,
})
```

And when I'm populating the virtual nothing happens:

```
db.ToolRecord.find().populate("user")
```

However if I add "ref" to the `userId` in the schema, and do `.populate("userId")`, it works as expected, meaning the problem isn't with the relation between the models but rather in the virtual population.

Any ideas What I'm doing wrong?

if I add `mongoose.set("debug", true)`, I can see that adding the `.populate("user")` to the query products this output in mongoose debug logs:

```
users.find({}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {}})
```

and adding the `.populate("userId")` (which works) products this log:

```
users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("631a1fe960d1f82c7fa51a06") ], [Symbol(mongoose#trustedSymbol)]: true }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: {}})
```

so we can see where the problem lies. Question is why is that virtual population doesn't work?

I'm running mongoose 6

Comment: I didn't know about `mongoose.set("debug", true)` and it just saved me, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `virtuals: true` option on the `toJSON` and `toObject()` options.

```
const toolRecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);
```

Comment: this works tho in the docs it doesn't say it's required